# Get all values that belong to a model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `Community` model, and each of these communities can have `badges`. My question is, how would I assign badges to a community, then display them in a view. I've looked into Laravel Relationships but I have failed to make them work even though the scenario fits their purpose.

I have 3 tables:

`communities` - Table full of communities registered to application.

`community_badges` - Which contains the columns `id`, `community_id` and `badge_type`

`badge_types` - Which contains information about each badge, such as it's name, description ect...

The `community_id`  in the `community_badges` table refers to the `id` in the `badge_types` table. When I'm getting the badges via eloquent and displaying them in the view, it doesn't matter which communities have the badges, all of the communities have the same badges.

How would I assign the `badges` to specific `communities` and the display them in the view?

(Current Code in View:)

```
    public function index()
    {
        $communitiesIds = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('community_id');
        $communities = Community::whereIn('id', $communitiesIds)->get();

        $badgeTypeId = CommunityBadge::where('community_id', $communitiesIds)->pluck('badge_type');
        $badges = BadgeType::whereIn('id', $badgeTypeId)->get();

        return view('home', compact('communities', 'badges'));
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show us your relations on your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your db structure like this

```
communities:id, ...
badge_types:id, ...
community_badges:community_id,badge_type_id, ...
```

Define your relations

In Community model define

```
public function badge_types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BadgeTypes::class, 'community_badges');
    // or when you not change db structure  
    //return $this->belongsToMany(BadgeTypes::class, 'community_badges', 'community_id','badge_type');
}
```

Usage

```
$communities = Community::with('badge_types')->get();
foreach($communities as $community) {
    $communityBadges = $community->badge_types;
    // other logic here 
}
```

Edit:

```
public function index()
{
    $communitiesIds = CommunityMemberList::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('community_id');
    $communities = Community::whereIn('id', $communitiesIds)->with('badge_types')->get();

    return view('home', compact('communities'));
}
```

In view code like this

```
@foreach($communities as $community) 
    @php($communityBadges = $community->badge_types)

    @foreach($communityBadges as $badgeType) 
        {{ $badgeType->id }} 
    // other logic here 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Property [badge_types] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Ah, I left the `dd()` in there which wasn't returning the variable. Rookie mistake. Thanks, it is working now :)

Comment: Ok. Glade help you